# AVCaptureMetadataOutput().rectOfInterest not Working

Tags: swift, qr-code, cgrect, avcapturedevice

I am building a `UIView` that has an overlaid box and the end-goal is to have the QR Code reader only fire when the QR falls within the box. I know that I need to set the `.rectOfInterest()` to be the same as the yellow box, but in the current implementation (code below), the reader doesn't work.

```
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) {
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            session.addInput(input)
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }

        let scannerRect = CGRect(x: self.center.x - (self.frame.width * 0.667 / 2), y: self.frame.width * 0.667 / 4, width: self.frame.width * 0.667, height: self.frame.width * 0.667)

        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        output.rectOfInterest = scannerRect
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        output.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]

        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = self.layer.bounds

        scannerBounds.frame = scannerRect
        scannerBounds.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        scannerBounds.borderWidth = 5

        self.layer.addSublayer(video)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(scannerBounds, above: video)
    }
}
```

Please help me align the box and the qr code reader.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First off, are you committing the session config and starting the capture session?

```
session.commitConfiguration()
session.startRunning()
```

Next, you need to convert the rect represented in the `UIView`'s coordinates into the coordinate system of the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`:

```
output.rectOfInterest = video.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: scannerRect)
```

Lastly, you might need to adjust the sequence of things. I was running into an issue where the rect of interest was not working correctly. It turns out that setting `rectOfInterest` before the view has been fully laid out might cause it not to work as expected.

On iOS 11 and upwards I'm setting `rectOfInterest` inside the view's `safeAreaInsetsDidChange` and then starting the camera.

On iOS 10 and lower, I'm doing this in the view controller's `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Works for me. For others sake: here is what I did...I have a public func called startScanner() that prior just called `session.startRunning()`. However, it now has 1. `session.commitConfiguration`, 2. `session.startRunning()`, 3. `output.rectOfInterest = video.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: scannerRect)`. Thanks again for the help.