# AV Foundation camera scan within box

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, barcode-scanner

[image]

I am able to scan barcode with full camera resolution successfully but i want that it should scan barcodes only within a particular frame(box which is centrally placed). if barcode lies outside that frame it should not scan.

```
var session         : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer    : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var highlightView   : UIView = UIView()

func opencamera()
    {
      if session.running
        {

        }
        else
        {
            session = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the captureDevice.

            let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

            session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority
            // Create input object.
            let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

            do {
                videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
            } catch {
                return
            }

            // Add input to the session.
            if (session.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
                session.addInput(videoInput)
            } else {
                scanningNotPossible()
            }
            let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

            // Add output to the session.
            if (session.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
                session.addOutput(metadataOutput)

                // Send captured data to the delegate object via a serial queue.
                metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

                // Set barcode type for which to scan: EAN-13.
                //metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
                metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                                                      AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,

                ]

            } else {
                scanningNotPossible()
            }
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session);
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.frame

            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            previewLayer?.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds))
                           image.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);
                            session.startRunning()
        }
    }
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        //var highlightViewRect = CGRectZero

        // var barCodeObject : AVMetadataObject!

        var detectionString : String!

        let barCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                            AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                            ]


        // The scanner is capable of capturing multiple 2-dimensional barcodes in one scan.
        for metadata in metadataObjects {

            for barcodeType in barCodeTypes {


                let decodedData:  AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject =  metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
                if metadata.type == barcodeType {

                                           detectionString = (metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject).stringValue
                    if(metadata.type  == AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code){
                        if (detectionString.hasPrefix("0") && detectionString.characters.count > 1){
                            detectionString = String(detectionString.characters.dropFirst())
                        }

                    }
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
                    self.session.stopRunning()

                    break
                }



            }
        }

        print(detectionString)

        self.previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.highlightView.removeFromSuperview()

    }
```

Comment: what is 'highlightView' in this code?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a `rectOfInterest` for your `AVCaptureMetaDataOutput`.

```
self.metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = [self.previewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:myRectOfInterest];
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturemetadataoutput/1616291-rectofinterest)

> rectOfInterest A rectangle of interest for limiting the search area
>   for visual metadata.
>
> The value of this property is a CGRect value that determines the
>   object’s rectangle of interest for each frame of video.
>
> The rectangle's origin is top left and is relative to the coordinate
>   space of the device providing the metadata.
>
> Specifying a rectangle of interest may improve detection performance
>   for certain types of metadata. Metadata objects whose bounds do not
>   intersect with the rectOfInterest will not be returned.
>
> The default value of this property is a rectangle of (0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
>   1.0).

Note that the value is not your pixels. Take a look at SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401364/how-do-i-use-the-metadataoutputrectofinterestforrect-method-and-rectofinterest-p) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634036/xcode-avcapturesession-scan-barcode-in-specific-frame-rectofinterest-is-not-wor) for more info.